# Browser shows plain text instead of HTML in mac

Tags: html, macos, firefox, browser

I want to write an html document like this :

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

I wrote it and saved it in my desktop with the name `hello.html` , but when I open this file with firefox or safari, the browser shows the whole text (including `<html>` and all of the texts) instead of only showing `my first heading`!
what's the problem?

Comment: Do you have hide extensions turned on? Because you could have saved the file as hello.html.txt. Use right click -> Get Info to check.

Comment: no, hide extensions is turned off, the name was first hello.html.rtf, but I renamed it to hello.html

Comment: Then you saved it as an rtf, which is not plain text. Go to the top menu bar -> text edit -> preferences and select plain text at the top. And then save it again.

Comment: My case was a little different but this is the first result on Google so I'll place this here. I was returning the HTML back from a REST endpoint, and it was also showing as text. The issue was the absence of a "content-type" header with the value "text/html". Once added, HTML was displaying as expected.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem was that I wrote the HTML document with "Text Edit" application, and it saved the file with `.rtf` extension, that is not plain text, so changing the name of file to `hello.html` didn't change anything.

there are two ways to fix this problem:

1) if you insist on using "Text Edit" you should go to `text edit->preferences` and tick the `plain text` at top of the page, then when you save something, it is saved as plain text

2) you can use some text editor, like lime edit

Comment: Checking in, in case it's useful for anyone else. On TextEdit version 1.13 (333), this option is Format > Make plain text.

Comment: Just to add, I also changed text edit->preference->open and save->display html files as html code instead of formatted text. Without this i was not able to see the html code written.

Answer (score 4):

The most likely reason is that you used a WYSIWYG editor and saved the document as HTML.

This created an HTML representation of the HTML source code you typed.

Use a text editor instead. I'm fond of Sublime Edit 2.

Comment: Use a text editor (or force TextEditor to save in plain text mode … but getting a decent editor would be better, you get other benefits like syntax highlighting).

Comment: It is what I use. There are lots of options out there. TextWrangler is free.

Comment: Why is the choice of the editor important for which file extension is set to a file on save?

Comment: @feeela — It isn't and I never said it was. The OP had two problems. This answer addresses only one of them. The other was resolved in comments.

Comment: @quentin what should I do now ? accept your answer and vote up user23127's comment, or write an answer that contains both ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a text editor such as Dreamweaver, Sublime

Sublime
http://www.sublimetext.com/2

and ensure your file ends in .html not .txt

Comment: What does the editor has to do with the file extensions given for a file? (Except nothing.)

Comment: Just in case. Opening a new window with Sublime text without changing the format could result in this (I mean hello.html.txt).

Comment: @feeela Look at the answer below, see what happens. Its a common thing. I did this simply to make OP aware while troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Download install "TextWrangler" (for mac) paste your html content to a new file in it and save with .html link. Dont use TextEdit.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the file using a basic text editor (like nano from the terminal), you'll probably see there's a lot of additional lines added to your basic HTML code. That's what happened to me.

I removed all the lines except what I wanted and it finally rendered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue in TextEdit. The resolution is - go to "Format", then "Make plain text". Save the document and open it again in browser. It had worked in my case. Hope it will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the parent folder on my web server contained an old `.htaccess` file that was causing HTML files to display as plain text.  Renaming/reworking the `.htaccess` file or just moving my HTML file to another folder fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

TextEdit setting change fixed this issue for me : text edit->preferences>New document>Fromat>plain text (unmark Rich text).

Answer (score -1):

I have same issue.
I am using TextEdit.  Issue was fixed by following the change: text edit->preferences>New document>Fromat>plain text (not Rich text).