# html code displayed as plain text in browsers

Tags: html

I've been teaching myself HTML lately and I was trying to test my new knowledge creating an actual HTML file from scratch.

I am using a Mac so after reading many online guides I used TextEdit to manage and edit my code.

So I write in all my code. Save it as name.html (making sure that the file is indeed HTML and not name.html.txt) and then I launch it with google chrome only to find out that my code is not interpreted as HTML but as plain text.

Why is this happening and how can I make the HTML be interpreted as HTML?

I tried modifying my code by removing some spaces also double checking everything was correct I even tried using other browsers with no success...

So here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is a test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is a quick test</h1>
    <p>This website is made for personal use so I can try out my new knowledge on HTML5 and CSS.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This exact same code is being displayed like this when I launch it in my browser:
[(Browser screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYQ4j.png)

Comment: Do you open your html file with your browser and not a text editor? Your code is correct. Then something else is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't adding a .txt extension at the end but you can't see it in your file manager? Try clicking enter to rename the file in Finder and make sure the ending/extension is truly .html and not .html.txt

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14439919/1052906

Comment: Are you sure you saved the file as plain text? By default TextEdit applies formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browser shows plain text instead of HTML in mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439513/browser-shows-plain-text-instead-of-html-in-mac)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a problem with TextEdit. Open it with another editor and save it again. See if that fixes it.

You can also edit TextEdit so it will work with HTML. You can learn do that [here](https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-configure-textedit-for-coding-html--mac-44786).

Comment: I'd recommend using brackets which also allows you to live preview your code

Answer (score 2):

With the file open in google chrome, right click anywhere in the screen then click on "view page source".

You will see the file opened up in a new tab

with the url in the url bar starting with view-source:

If you see a bunch of stuff that isn't what you originally typed into your file, then what has happened is that TextEdit probably saved your file as some form of rich text instead of plain text, even though the file extension is .html.   I looked at the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextEdit) for TextEdit and it told me that TextEdit can be used for producing rich text documents.  If this happens to be the case (I can't be 100% sure because I'm not a mac person and I've never used the TextEdit program) then you would want to use a different text editor to edit the source code of your html file.

Comment: Please don't give software recommendations in answers, as they can be perceived as spam. Simply answer the question with code or theory, as you have done, and leave out the unsolicited product advise.