# Why do I keep redirecting to the wrong post using sessions in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, session, redirect

I am making a WordPress plugin that allows users to create a post on the frontend and then automatically redirects them to the post they just created. I have to use two separate functions and a session variable to achieve this because wp_redirect can't be used after the header has been sent. The issue that I am running in to is the session variable is not sending the permalink for the post that was just created and is instead sending the previous post's permalink.

The function below is initialized when the user submits a form

```
function create_post(){
    
if(is_user_logged_in())
{
    if(isset($_POST['ispost']))
    {
     
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();

        $user_login = $current_user->user_login;
        $user_email = $current_user->user_email;
        $user_firstname = $current_user->user_firstname;
        $user_lastname = $current_user->user_lastname;
        $user_id = $current_user->ID;

        $post_title = $_POST['title'];
        $sample_image = $_FILES['sample_image']['name'];
        $post_content = $_POST['sample_content'];
        $category = $_POST['category'];

        $new_post = array(
            'post_title' => $post_title,
            'post_content' =>$post_content,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            'post_category' => $category
        );
    
        $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
        add_post_meta($pid, 'meta_key', true);
       $_SESSION['pid'] = get_post_field( 'post_name', $pid );
        if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata'))
        {
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
        }
        if ($_FILES)
        {
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array)
            {
                if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
                {
                    return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
                }
                $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $pid );
            }
        }
        if ($attach_id > 0)
        {
            //and if you want to set that image as Post then use:
            update_post_meta($pid, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
            $_SESSION['pid'] = $pid->post_name;
            
        }

        $my_post1 = get_post($attach_id);
        $my_post2 = get_post($pid);
        $my_post = array_merge($my_post1, $my_post2);
        
        
    }
    

}
else
{
    echo "<h2 style='text-align:center;'>User must be login for add post!</h2>";
}
}
```

and this function is supposed to redirect the user to the post that was just created on init

```
add_action('init', 'myInit');
function myInit() {
    if (isset($_POST['ispost'])) {
        $errors = myFormValidation();
        if (empty($errors)) {
            
           // echo get_permalink($pid);
            $url = 'https://somethingsomething.com/'. $_SESSION['pid'];
            wp_redirect($url);
            

          
        }
        //Set the errors here
    }
}
```

How can I make $_SESSION['pid'] send the current post's permalink and not the previous one?

Comment: When is the `create_post()` function run? Where is the `add_action()` for that function? Does it run before or after the `myInit()` function?

Comment: create_post() runs when when the form is submittted by the user with a html form action attribute

Answer (score 0):

Probably the redirection is going to the wrong place because the `myInit()` function runs before the `create_post()` function.

### wp_redirect

You need to add `exit()` immediately after the call to `wp_redirect();` or you will have unexpected results.

### To Redirect the User

You could do the following.

1. Try to process the form before the headers are sent and use wp_redirect() to redirect the user.

I guess this would work in theory, but probably it's not ideal since I assume the `create_post()` function is being handled with an `admin_post_(action)` hook which runs **after** the headers are sent.

or

2. Use JavaScript to redirect the user **after** the headers are sent.

You can redirect the user after processing the form by using JavaScript.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'window.location = "' . $url . '"';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: Where would I implement this? when I try to put it after add_post_meta it just puts window.location = "' . $url . '" as plain text inside the form instead of redirecting. If I put it within myinit() it will redirect but session['pid'] Returns blank. I've tried changing the hook to 'wp' as well and still return nothing

Comment: If it adds it as plain text then it's being escaped first (which it shouldn't be) because `<script type="text/javascript">` is an html tag.  Put it in the function that handles the post request, which I assume is `create_post()` in this case.

Comment: i am echoing the script within the create_post() method right after add_post_meta and it is still coming back as plain text. I have also tried putting it after array_merge() at the bottom and at the top of the create_post() function

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why your html tags are echoing as plain text. Make sure you're not using `<plaintext>`, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107855/, https://www.quora.com/Why-would-a-web-page-be-displayed-as-plain-text-instead-of-HTML, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439513/, 
`there might be some closing of tag issue, which causes browser to not read the code written properly hence showing text in browser.`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating session variables for all of the inputs and then creating the post after the linked page loads and it worked. I then used JavaScript to redirect to the newly created post.

```
if(is_user_logged_in())
{
    if(isset($_POST['ispost']))
    {
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();

        $user_login = $current_user->user_login;
        $user_email = $current_user->user_email;
        $user_firstname = $current_user->user_firstname;
        $user_lastname = $current_user->user_lastname;
        $user_id = $current_user->ID;


        $_SESSION['post_title']=$_POST['title'];
        $_SESSION['sample_image']=$_FILES['sample_image']['name'];
        $_SESSION['post_content']=$_POST['sample_content'] . do_shortcode('[wpstream_go_live]'); 
        // do_shortcode('[wpstream_go_live id="12"]'); 
        $_SESSION['post_category']=$_POST['category'];

        //$post_title = $_POST['title'];
        //$sample_image = $_FILES['sample_image']['name'];
        //$post_content = $_POST['sample_content'];
        //$category = $_POST['category'];
    }
}


add_action('loop_end', 'myInit');
function myInit() {
    if (isset($_POST['ispost'])) {
        $errors = myFormValidation();
        if (empty($errors)) {
            echo $_SESSION['post_title'];
                $new_post = array(
                'post_title' => $_SESSION['post_title'],
                'post_content' => $_SESSION['post_content'] . $_SESSION['post_category'],
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type' => $post_type,
                'post_category' =>array($_SESSION['post_category']) 
            );

            $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
            add_post_meta($pid, 'meta_key', true);
            
            $url= get_permalink($pid);
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
            //echo 'alert("' . $pid . '")';
            echo 'window.location = "' . $url . '"';
            echo '</script>';    
            
            //echo do_shortcode('[wpstream_go_live id="12"]');
            
            $_SESSION['pid'] = $pid;
            $url= "www.google.com";
        
            if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata'))
            {
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
            }

            if ($_FILES)
            {
                foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array)
                {
                    if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
                    {
                        return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
                    }
                    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $pid );
                }
            }
            
            if ($attach_id > 0)
            {
                //and if you want to set that image as Post then use:
                update_post_meta($pid, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
                $_SESSION['pid'] = $pid;
                
            }
    
            $my_post1 = get_post($attach_id);
            $my_post2 = get_post($pid);
            $my_post = array_merge($my_post1, $my_post2);
        }
    } else {
        echo "<h2 style='text-align:center;'>User must be login for add post!</h2>";
        //echo do_shortcode('[wpstream_go_live id="12"]');
        echo PLUGIN_DIR;
    }
}
```